# CSS: margin-top to a block affects to the container div

Tags: css, margin

I have this [page](http://tirengarfio.com/).

I want to give a margin-top to the logo, but when i do it, the div that contains the logo goes also down, why?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins define spaces around elements.  Perhaps you need to use Padding instead.

Comment: Yes, it works, but.. margin also define spaces around elements ?!

Comment: Margin takes up actual space, padding does not.

For example, if you were setting up left & right margins, and you had one big content area of 960px, and you added margins of 10px on the left & right, your content area would now be 980px.  If you just used padding, your content area would not increase.